# Reading a large number of .csv files in Python pandas and assigning different variable names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a number of csv files named file0001.csv to file0100.csv
I would like to read each one in turn and assign a variable name to it. I think the best way to do this would be as a loop.
The variable name here should be x1 with the data from file0001.csv inside it

For example:

```
FileNumber=1
while FileNumber < 101:
    x+'FileNumber'=read_csv('C:/file'+str(FileNumber).zfill(4)+'.csv')
    FileNumber=FileNumber+1

x001.head()
```

The read_csv part works fine but the x+'FileNumber' attempt at creating a variable name does not.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you have a lot of data items of the same type, it's advisable to use a list or similar container. I'd do:

```
file_number = 1
files = []
while file_number <= 100:
    file_name = 'C:/file%04d.csv' % file_number
    files.append(read_csv(file_name))
    file_number += 1

files[0].head()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try creating a dictionary rather than having tons or variable names

```
filedict = {}
while FileNumber < 101:
    key = 'Filenumber'+str(Filenumber)
    value = read_csv('C:/file'+str(FileNumber).zfill(4)+'.csv')
    filedict[key] = value 
    FileNumber  += 1
```

This way the `key` is your variable and you assign a `value` for each key.  It's like a contained list of variable names and values.